# Add a entire directory to hadoop file system (hdfs)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have data that is stored within the sub directories and would like to put the parent directory in the HDFS. The data is always present at the last directory and the directory structure extends upto 2 levels. 
So the structure is [parent_dir]->[sub_directories]->[sub_directories]->data

I tried to add the entire directory by doing

```
hadoop fs -put parent_dir input
```

This takes a long long time ! The sub directories are possibly 258X258. And this eventually fails with

```
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(X.X.X.245:50010, storageID=DS-262356658-X.X.X.245-50010-1394905028736, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020):DataXceiver
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskOutOfSpaceException: No space left on devic
```

I can see the required space on the nodes. What am I doing wrong here ?

Also I the way I was planning to access my files was

```
hadoop jar Computation.jar input/*/* output
```

This worked well for small data set.

Answer (score 0):

That error message is usually fundamentally correct.  You may not be taking into account the replication factor for the HDFS filesystem.  If your replication factor is set to 3, which is the default, then you need 300GB of storage available to store a 100GB dataset.

There are a couple of things you can do to help get around the issue:

1) Decrease your replication factor (dfs.replication), and your maximum blocks (dfs.replication.max) to 2 in your hdfs-site.xml

2) Compress your datasets.  Hadoop can operate on bzip and gzip compressed files (though you need to be careful of splitting)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, the replication factor is 1 in my case. And the size of my entire folder is just 500MB !

Comment: How many files are in the data folder?  Could you be exceeding the NameNode memory space with a massive number of small files?

Comment: i dont see more than 6-7 txt files in the folder. Am I doing this right? I mean trying to copy the entire folder to hdfs?

Comment: I performed a quick test ... `hadoop fs -put work/reuters-sgm test` worked just fine.  There isn't anything wrong with the syntax.

Comment: Okay, lets look for the odd things ... `su - hdfs -c "hdfs dfsadmin -report"`.  All storage info in there checks out?  Decommission status is "Normal"?

Comment: I am unable to run the above command directly? Is there something that i need to prepend ?

Comment: Next up is a quick fsck verification to make sure you path is healthy:  `su - hdfs -c "hdfs /path/input"`.  And following that is a check to make sure you're not quotaed:  `hadoop fs -count -q /path`.  If the first 4 fields are "none,inf,none, none", you're not quotaed.

Comment: Ah ... Running the su commands probably has to be done via the root account, or sudo.

Comment: I tried this hadoop fs -count -q /path, but i get "Can not find listing for /path". Also I am unable to run the first command thorws error cannot find hdfs. Should that be run with hadoop shell ?

Comment: Sorry, yeah, all of those commands are for the command line.  They are useful for diagnosing problems.  The /path variable should be the location where you're trying to storing data on hdfs.

Comment: And this is what I get "none  inf   none  inf"